# Click event does not fire on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#sampleid').bind('click', function(e) {
    // a call is made to the plugin to construct a dialog box, the id "someid" is passed as an argument to this plugin
    $('#someid').bind('click', function() {});
}
```

I have this click event which doesn't fire on the first click but works fine from second click onwards.
The samplefunction function calls another plugin , which constructs dialog box. "someid", is passed as an argument to this plugin.

I have a problem with the first click. Nothing happens on the first click , if you click again , the click event behaves properly.

Comment: Can you show when you calling samplefunction.

Comment: You are going to have to make a working example with the problem or we will not be able to help you out.

Comment: Are you adding someid dynamically on page load ?

Comment: Please check it out now.

Comment: Do not bind click events inside click events unless you are properly cleaning up from the previous click to prevent multiple bindings. What happens if the user clicks that button twice? or 20 times?

Answer (score 5):

For binding events, you probably want to put it in document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#somid").bind("click", function () {
        // do something
    });
});
```

If you want to bind it after a certain event (like something calling `sampleFunction`, then it won't be available until after. I'm guessing you're triggering `sampleFunction` on click of the element already.

If you need to have it available for any time that "someid" is on the page, you should use `on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

This "fixes" the "shortcomings" that `bind` has.

Comment: +1 *"I'm guessing you're triggering sampleFunction on click of the element already."*

Comment: yes the function is triggered on a click give me a second i will post an edited version of the code

Comment: Is the function triggered every time that click happens? Sounds like a recipe for getting the same click event bound on the element n times where n is the number of times you click on it plus 1 * n

Comment: yes every time the click happens the plugin is called the dialog is constructed and the bind takes place.

Comment: @RahulMore Just post your code so we can figure out how to change it so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is recommended now.

```
var samplefunction =  function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#someid', function(){
        //do something ;
    });
}
```

Comment: If you did use .on to solve this problem, it shouldn't be inside of samplefunction unless samplefunction is only ran once.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Bind Use on function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var samplefunction =  function(){
        //  
        $('#someid').on('click',function(){
        do something ;
        });
       }

    });
```

Comment: I believe `live` is deprecated. Use `on`.

Comment: replacing `.bind` with `.on` in the way you now have it is exactly the same as what he is currently using.